# ISAPI Rewrite if file with .ext exists then allow it as a folder URL

Tags: asp-classic, url-rewriting, isapi-rewrite

I am trying to do the following...

If a page called `login.asp` exists then allow a rewrite for it as /login/ but do not allow a direct access to `login.asp`.

Here is my code so far.

```
# Helicon ISAPI_Rewrite configuration file
# Version 3.1.0.87

RewriteEngine On
# if file is not exists
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 !-f

# if folder is not exists
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 !-d

# From start to end, "^(\w+)[/]+$" only matches with one or more alphanumeric characters and "_".
# Alternatively can end with one or more slashes.
# Change [R = 302, L] to [L] if you want make a rewrite instead of redirect.

RewriteRule ^(\w+)[/]*$ /username.asp?username=$1 [L]
```

So if you imagine the user types `www.web.com/contact` if there is a page called `contact.asp` it displays that rewritten content. If the .asp page does not exist then it loads the content from `/user.asp?username=contact` to check if it is a user profile.

Much appreciated!

C

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
RewriteEngine On
# if reqiested url+.asp exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.asp -f
# if folder does not exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
Rewrite requested one-level url to target place
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ /username.asp?username=$1 [NC,L]
```